# Does Prettier add a newline at EOF or not?

Tags: prettier

When looking for whether Prettier adds a newline at the EOF or not I get mixed results and I cannot find a definitive answer. Issues in the project are contradicting and I cannot find it in the official docs.

I want the newline at EOF. Colleagues commit files without it so I need to know what is happening. There is an editorconfig where I'll add a `insert_final_newline = true` for CS files, and I know Rider and VSS and VS Code have their own settings for this, so I am hoping that people are using editorconfig or Prettier.

But it would be nice to know for sure whether Prettier adds or removes the newline at EOF.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Prettier will ensure that files *always* end with a single newline.

See this relevant passage from the project's [rationale page on empty lines](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines):

> - Prettier collapses multiple blank lines into a single blank line.
> - Empty lines at the start and end of blocks (and whole files) are removed. (**Files always end with a single newline**, though [emphasis added].)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. see this issue for more info: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6360#issuecomment-518994475

Comment: Yair Kukielka, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)